# Automated Email of KnitR reports on Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos, email, automation

I am generating pdf reports using KnitR and would like to automate emailing of these reports from our companies' server. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: One step at a time? Generating PDFs with knitr and sending an email with attachment are both do-able but seem unrelated. Sending mail you can use the [sendmailR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/sendmailR.pdf), [here's an example](http://www.ancienteco.com/2012/05/send-emails-with-attachments-from-r.html). I don't see what knitr has to do with your question if you're already generating the reports.

Comment: thank you for your response. Yes, you are correct. I need to do the email as part of a batch execution in R. I cannot get sendmailR to work, but likely has to do with some settings on my machine.